# How to rotate an image using pure javascript in old browsers

Tags: javascript

It was several years ago (almost 7 years) when I wanted to rotate an image in **IE6**. I searched and I found a JavaScript code that rotated an image. I started reading the code and I found out that in some parts of that code the Shift operator has been employed for rotating an image. 
I was wondering how we can rotate an image **without** using frameworks and new features in the new browsers like CSS3, ....

Is the shift operators can help us to rotate an image? If so, how?

Comment: I think IE6 would still use CSS filters.

Comment: As I can remember, It didn't use the CSS filters. But I don't know. Maybe. But 7 years ago, I think css didn't support image rotation.

Comment: At the time, IE6 had its own proprietary CSS filters that did indeed support rotation.

Comment: Any code sample using JavaScript?

Comment: I would say JavaScript will be helpless here as canvas is not supported in IE6. Go with filters.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're now trying to do this in modern browsers only? (i.e. no IE6 support?)

Answer (score 0):

In internet explorer 6 and 8 you can use a filter in the CSS to rotate images.

To rotate 45 degrees you can use code like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
```